# Cannot import recently created package

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the structure of my repository:

```
├── README.md
├── core
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── entrypoint.sh
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── sentinel.py
│   └── site.conf
└── python_package
    ├── sentinel
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── sentinel.py
    └── setup.py
```

It has two directories. The main one is `core` which holds the code of the service itself. I wanted to create a helper package to interact with this service, so I created `python_package` and added to `sentinel.py` a helper class (`Sentinel`). `__init__.py` is empty.

The content of `setup.py` is:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(name='sentinel',
      version='0.1',
      description='Client to interact with the Sentinel service',
      url='https://foo/bar/sentinel.git',
      author='yzT',
      author_email='yzT@example.com',
      packages=find_packages(),
      install_requires='requests')
```

When I activate a virtualenv and install `pip install .`, the package is installed along with the `requests` dependency. If then I open a python terminal and try to import the class `from sentinel import Sentinel` it's reporting: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Sentinel' from 'sentinel' (/Users/yzT/sentinel/python_package/sentinel/__init__.py)` and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have correctly understood your question, the package is `sentinel` it contains a `sentinel.py` module which in turns contains a `Sentinel` class. In that case, you must add one level:

```
from sentinel.sentinel import Sentinel
```

Alternatively, you can import some symbols into the package through its `__init__.py` file. If `python_package/sentinel/__init__.py` contains (please notice the dot (`.`)):

```
from .sentinel import Sentinel
```

then the `Sentinel` symbol will exist directly in the package, and you can use in your external script:

```
from .sentinel import Sentinel
```